# jQuery Content Slider w/o Universal Nav Buttons

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm looking for a jQuery Content Slider plugin (dime a dozen) but I need one that doesn't use a "universal" navigation structure. I need to be able to define my own back and next buttons per slide and optionally not have a back button or have multiple next buttons.

By that I mean I have 3 slides with html content and/or form fields in them. I want to define my own anchor links to proceed or to go back. I would like to be able to do this through data-attributes or putting a class name of 'back' or 'next' on them.

This doesn't seem that difficult but I've yet to find an out of the box solution that doesn't have universal arrows, buttons, etc. If you know of one I would be very grateful. I'd like it also support a slide in transition but not a requirement and I don't need it to support any auto timing functionality.

### Example:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    // form
    <a class="next">Submit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    // content
    <a class="next">Select Me</a>
    // content
    <a class="next">No Select Me</a>
    // content
    <a class="next">Select Me Instead</a>
    <a class="back">Go Back and Edit that Form</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    // content
    <a class="next">Continue On</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Bootstrap's carousel.js file supports this functionality.

All you've got to do is add a couple data-attributes:

- data-slide="next"
- data-target="#slider"

The resulting code for the example above would be:

```
<div id="slider">
  <div class="slide">
    // form
    <a data-slide="next" data-target="#slider">Submit</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    // content
    <a data-slide="next" data-target="#slider">Select Me</a>
    // content
    <a data-slide="next" data-target="#slider">No Select Me</a>
    // content
    <a data-slide="next" data-target="#slider">Select Me Instead</a>
    <a data-slide="prev" data-target="#slider">Go Back and Edit that Form</a>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">
    // content
    <a data-slide="next" data-target="#slider">Continue On</a>
  </div>
</div>
```